# How do advertise networks drive ad to publisher slots by javascript tag embed?

Tags: javascript, api, ads, slots, advertisement-server

Advertising networks such as Google, Taboola, and others are linking advertisers and publishers as an advertising ecosystem to drive ads to publisher slots (Nativ/HTML5/Banner..ex).

by javascript tag...How do ad networks handle and show those ads into publisher slots by including javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The javascript tag makes an HTTP request to an ad network's server - an ad server. This request will contain some information, like which browser is used, the browser's language setting, data stored in a cookie, the URL of the website, etc. Furthermore, the HTTP request contains the IP address, which can be used to identify the user's location (at least on the country level).
The ad server picks an ad that matches the ad request, considering the available data about the user and what the advertiser is willing to pay for it.

After this ad selection process, the ad server responds to the HTTP request with the URL of the ad's resource, and the javascript tag loads this resource into the slot.

This is a simplified explanation of the process of loading ads. In real life, this whole process is much more complex than described.